# Web Scraping Multiple Links with PyQt / QtWebkit

Tags: python, qt, qt4, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a large website of government records which requires a "snowball" method, i.e., starting at the main search page and then following each link that the scraper finds to the next page.

I've been able to load the main page using PyQt [this SiteScraper tutorial](http://blog.sitescraper.net/2010/06/scraping-javascript-webpages-in-python.html#comment-form).

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

class Render(QWebPage):
      def __init__(self, url):
           self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
           QWebPage.__init__(self)
           self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
           self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
           self.app.exec_()

      def _loadFinished(self, result):
           self.frame = self.mainFrame()
           self.app.quit()

def main():
    baseUrl = 'http://www.thesite.gov'
    url = 'http://www.thesite.gov/search'
    r = Render(url)
    html = r.frame.toHtml()
    # use BeautifulSoup to cycle through each regulation
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

regs = soup.find('div',{'class':'x-grid3-body'}).findAll('a')

# cycle through list and call up each page separately
for reg in regs:
    link = baseUrl + reg['href']
    link = str(link)
    # use Qt to load each regulation page
    r = Render(link)

    html = r.frame.toHtml() # get actual rendered web page
```

The problem is I get this error when I try to render a new webpage:

```
RuntimeError: A QApplication instance already exists.
```

I get it that the function is trying to call another QApplication instance.  But how do I navigate to a new page with the same instance?

---

```
class Render(QWebPage):
     def __init__(self, app, url):
          QWebPage.__init__(self)
          self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
          self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
          app.exec_()

     def _loadFinished(self, result):
          self.frame = self.mainFrame()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    baseUrl = 'http://www.thesite.gov'
    url = 'http://www.thesite.gov/search'

    r = Render(app, url)
    html = r.frame.toHtml()
```

Comment: Unless you are using it to actually view things (including running JavaScript on the page), there's no point whatsoever in using Qt or Webkit. `urllib2.urlopen` or [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) (which I recommend you use) will serve you much better and will be considerably faster and reduce resource usage.

Comment: @Chris Morgan I absolutely agree, but the pages I'm trying to view (www.regulations.gov) are almost completely JavaSript driven. At this point I've tried to use urllib2, Scrapy, Selenium, and now Qt.  The only one that seems to work is Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK then. If you really need JavaScript. (Can you get the answer from JSON at all? That would probably be easier still with `simplejson` or `json`.) The answer is *don't make more than one QApplication*. You're not allowed to. Make `main` make a `QApplication` and then use the `QWebPage` without bothering to call `QApplication.exec_()`. If that doesn't work, run it all in another `QThread`.

Comment: You mean like the code I added above?  That seems to get stuck somewhere -- no output, never finishes.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem (needing to load multiple pages with QWebPage) but I couldn't get any of these answers to work for me.  Here's what did work, the key is to use a **QEventLoop** and connect loadFinished to loop.quit:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
import sys

def loadPage(url):
      page = QtWebKit.QWebPage()
      loop = QtCore.QEventLoop() # Create event loop
      page.mainFrame().loadFinished.connect(loop.quit) # Connect loadFinished to loop quit
      page.mainFrame().load(url)
      loop.exec_() # Run event loop, it will end on loadFinished
      return page.mainFrame().toHtml()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

urls = ['https://google.com', 'http://reddit.com', 'http://wikipedia.org']
for url in urls:
      print '-----------------------------------------------------'
      print 'Loading ' + url
      html = loadPage(url)
      print html

app.exit()
```

Posting a simplified example here compared to OP's to demonstrate the essential problem and solution.

Answer (score 3):

You're crazy man! QT has a much better DOM than beautifulsoup.

Replace:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

With

```
page = QWebPage()

page.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, False)
page.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, False)
page.mainFrame().setHtml(html)

dom = page.mainFrame().documentElement()
```

Then you can simply scrape data like so:

```
li = dom.findFirst("body div#content div#special ul > li")

if not li.isNull():
    class = li.attribute("class")
    text  = li.toPlainText()
```

Finally you should use QWebView instead of QWebPage. You can set it up to act like a server which can be controlled with a socket. This is what I do:

```
class QTimerWithPause(QTimer):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        super(QTimerWithPause, self).__init__ (parent)

        self.startTime = 0
        self.interval  = 0

        return

    def start(self, interval):

        from time import time

        self.interval  = interval
        self.startTime = time()

        super(QTimerWithPause, self).start(interval)

        return

    def pause(self):

        from time import time

        if self.isActive ():

            self.stop()

            elapsedTime = self.startTime - time()
            self.startTime -= elapsedTime

            # time() returns float secs, interval is int msec
            self.interval -= int(elapsedTime*1000)+1

        return

    def resume(self):

        if not self.isActive():
            self.start(self.interval)

        return


class CrawlerWebServer(QWebView):  

    TIMEOUT = 60
    STUPID  = r"(bing|yahoo|google)"

    def __init__(self, host="0.0.0.0", port=50007, parent=None, enableImages=True, enablePlugins=True):

        # Constructor

        super(CrawlerWebServer, self).__init__(parent)  

        self.command     = None
        self.isLoading   = True
        self.isConnected = False
        self.url         = QUrl("http://mast3rpee.tk/")
        self.timeout     = QTimerWithPause(self)
        self.socket      = QTcpServer(self)


        # 1: Settings

        self.settings().enablePersistentStorage()
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, enableImages)
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, enablePlugins)
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)

        # 2: Server
        if args.verbosity > 0: print "Starting server..."

        self.socket.setProxy(QNetworkProxy(QNetworkProxy.NoProxy))
        self.socket.listen(QHostAddress(host), int(port))
        self.connect(self.socket, SIGNAL("newConnection()"), self._connect)

        if args.verbosity > 1:
            print "    Waiting for connection(" + host + ":" + str(port) + ")..."

        # 3: Default page

        self._load(10*1000, self._loadFinished)

        return

    def __del__(self):

        try:
            self.conn.close()
            self.socket.close()
        except:
            pass

        return

    def _sendAuth(self):

        self.conn.write("Welcome to WebCrawler server (http://mast3rpee.tk)\r\n\rLicenced under GPL\r\n\r\n")

    def _connect(self): 

        self.disconnect(self.socket, SIGNAL("newConnection()"), self._connect)

        self.conn               = self.socket.nextPendingConnection()
        self.conn.nextBlockSize = 0

        self.connect(self.conn, SIGNAL("readyRead()"), self.io)
        self.connect(self.conn, SIGNAL("disconnected()"), self.close)
        self.connect(self.conn, SIGNAL("error()"), self.close)
        self._sendAuth()

        if args.verbosity > 1:
            print "    Connection by:", self.conn.peerAddress().toString()

        self.isConnected = True

        if self.isLoading == False:
            self.conn.write("\r\nEnter command:")

        return

    def io(self):

        if self.isLoading: return None

        if args.verbosity > 0:
            print "Reading command..."

        data = self.conn.read(1024).strip(" \r\n\t")

        if not data: return None

        elif self.command is not None:
            r = self.command(data)
            self.command = None
            return r

        return self._getCommand(data)

    def _getCommand(self, d):

        from re import search

        d = unicode(d, errors="ignore")

        if search(r"(help|HELP)", d) is not None:

            self.conn.write("URL | JS | WAIT | QUIT\r\n\r\nEnter Command:")

        elif search(r"(url|URL)", d) is not None:

            self.command = self._print

            self.conn.write("Enter address:")

        elif search(r"(js|JS|javascript|JAVASCRIPT)", d) is not None:

            self.command = self._js

            self.conn.write("Enter javascript to execte:")

        elif search(r"(wait|WAIT)", d) is not None:

            self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinishedPrint)
            self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  

        elif search(r"(quit|QUIT|exit|EXIT)", d) is not None:

            self.close()

        else:

            self.conn.write("Invalid command!\r\n\r\nEnter Command:")

        return

    def _print(self, d):

        u = d[:250]

        self.out(u)

        return True

    def _js(self, d):

        try:
            self.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(d)

        except:
            pass

        self.conn.write("Enter Javascript:")

        return True

    def _stop(self):

        from time import sleep

        if self.isLoading == False: return

        if args.verbosity > 0:
            print "    Stopping..."

        self.timeout.stop()
        self.stop()

    def _load(self, timeout, after):

        # Loads a page into frame / sets up timeout

        self.timeout.timeout.connect(self._stop)
        self.timeout.start(timeout)

        self.loadFinished.connect(after)  
        self.load(self.url)

        return

    def _loadDone(self, disconnect = None):

        from re   import search
        from time import sleep

        self.timeout.timeout.disconnect(self._stop)
        self.timeout.stop()

        if disconnect is not None:

            self.loadFinished.disconnect(disconnect)

            # Stick a while on the page

            if search(CrawlerWebServer.STUPID, self.url.toString(QUrl.RemovePath)) is not None:
                sleep(5)
            else:
                sleep(1)

        return

    def _loadError(self):

        from time import sleep, time

        if not self.timeout.isActive(): return True

        if args.verbosity > 0: print "    Error retrying..."

        # 1: Pause timeout

        self.timeout.pause()

        # 2: Check for internet connection

        while self.page().networkAccessManager().networkAccessible() == QNetworkAccessManager.NotAccessible: sleep(1)

        # 3: Wait then try again

        sleep(2)
        self.reload()
        self.timeout.resume()

        return False

    def go(self, url, after = None):

        # Go to a specific address

        global args

        if after is None:
            after = self._loadFinished

        if args.verbosity > 0:
            print "Loading url..."

        self.url        = QUrl(url)
        self.isLoading  = True

        if args.verbosity > 1:
            print "   ", self.url.toString()

        self._load(CrawlerWebServer.TIMEOUT * 1000, after)

        return

    def out(self, url):

        # Print html of a a specific url

        self.go(url, self._loadFinishedPrint)

        return

    def createWindow(self, windowType):  

        # Load links in the same web-view.

        return self  

    def _loadFinished(self, ok):

        # Default LoadFinished

        from time import sleep
        from re   import search

        if self.isLoading == False: return

        if ok == False:
            if not self._loadError(): return 

        self._loadDone(self._loadFinished)

        if args.verbosity > 1:
            print "    Done"

        if self.isConnected == True:
            self.conn.write("\r\nEnter command:")

        self.isLoading = False

        return

    def _loadFinishedPrint(self, ok):  

        # Print the evaluated HTML to stdout

        if self.isLoading == False: return

        if ok == False:
            if not self._loadError(): return 

        self._loadDone(self._loadFinishedPrint)  

        if args.verbosity > 1:
            print "    Done"

        h = unicode( self.page().mainFrame().toHtml(), errors="ignore" )

        if args.verbosity > 2:
            print "------------------\n" + h + "\n--------------------"

        self.conn.write(h)
        self.conn.write("\r\nEnter command:")

        self.isLoading  = False

        return

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):  

        # Context Menu

        menu = self.page().createStandardContextMenu()  
        menu.addSeparator()  
        action = menu.addAction('ReLoad')  

        @action.triggered.connect  
        def refresh():  
            self.load(self.url)

        menu.exec_(QCursor.pos())


class CrawlerWebClient(object):

    def __init__(self, host, port):

        import socket

        global args

        # CONNECT TO SERVER

        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        self.socket.connect((host, port))

        o = self.read()

        if args.verbosity > 2:
            print "\n------------------------------\n" + o + "\n------------------------------\n"

        return

    def __del__(self):

        try: self.socket.close()
        except: pass

    def read(self):

        from re import search

        r = ""

        while True:
            out = self.socket.recv(64*1024).strip("\r\n")

            if out.startswith(r"Enter"):
                break

            if out.endswith(r"Enter command:"):
                r += out[:-14]
                break

            r += out

        return r

    def command(self, command):

        global args

        if args.verbosity > 2:
            print "    Command: [" + command + "]\n------------------------------"

        self.socket.sendall(unicode(command))

        r =  self.read()

        if args.verbosity > 2:
            print r, "\n------------------------------\n"

        return r
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PyQt, but as an option, you could write your script without using a class. That way, you can more easily re-use that application instance.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Bad answer. That won't help at all. It's the fact that you can't use multiple `QApplication` instances that's the problem - he's putting that in the wrong spot, that's all.